# How do I webscrape without a unique class or identifier?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm quite new to python and am trying to use beautifulsoup tp webscrape some average temperature data from historic data from Wunderground.com. I've looked through webscraping tutorials but cannot find examples where the data being scraped is not easily accessible with a unique class or id. My code is as follows but I'm at a loss when trying access the webscraping data.

I'm trying to scrape the value in the average temperature column for this webpage and will want to scrape other values in the table too: https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gb/christchurch/EGHH/date/2019-8-11

The data I want is within a table but every row of the table has the class="ng-star-inserted" and there are 426 matches for "td.ng-star-inserted" on the page. I'm not sure how and if best to use beautifulsoup's find or find_all methods? All help appreciated, thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gb/christchurch/EGHH/date/2019-8-11'
response = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-temperature mat-column-temperature ng-star-inserted"
```

Comment: Could you please clarify by putting it in context?